# for in behavior different on MSIE 10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

The following jasmine test works on PhantomJS or Chrome, but not on MSIE 10.

```
describe("utility", function () {

    var utility = {
        // { A: true, B: true } will become 'AB'
        CombineValues: function (splitValues) {
            var combined = '';
            for (item in splitValues) { // on IE, item is a function, not a string
                if (splitValues[item])  // on IE, this returns false all the time
                    combined = combined + item;
            }
            return combined;
        },

        // 'AB' will become { A: true, B: true }
        SplitValues: function (combined) {
            var splitValues = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < combined.length; i++) {
                splitValues[combined.charAt(i)] = true;
            }

            return splitValues;
        }
    };

    it('CombineValues(SplitValues()) should be idempotent', function () {
        // on MSIE, result is '' instead of 'ABC'
        expect(utility.CombineValues(utility.SplitValues('ABC'))).toBe('ABC');
    });
});
```

What am I missing?

Thank you!

EDIT: on IE, item shows this:

```
function item() {
    [native code]
}
 {
    [prototype] :  function() {     [native code] } ,
    prototype : {...}
}
```

Comment: OK, the empty string is unexpected, but why do you expect this to be idempotent? The property order in objects is not defined, so `BCA` would be a valid result as well.

Comment: Try `for (var item`. Also, what does `console.log(item)` yield? If it is a function as you say I'd be curious which one.

Comment: Holy moly... @Bergi, var item made it work. Can you put it as an answer so that I can accept it? The order didn't matter to me so my test name is not exactly right if the order can be different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Internet Explorer, [`window.item` is a function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536460%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). A non-overwritable one apparently.

With your `for (item in …)` loop, you are implicitly assigning to that global variable, which (silently) fails in sloppy mode. Try to add a `"use strict";` and it should throw an error.

Use a local variable:

```
for (var item in splitValues) …
//   ^^^
```

In strict mode, assigning to an undeclared (in Chrome/Webkit) global variable would fail as well, in sloppy mode you're just creating a global `item` variable with that code.

Comment: Very nice. var fixes the problem on IE, and "use strict" does catch my mistake on Chrome. Thanks!